# What is the use of a C++ class containing an "implementation" and "interface" pointer to itself?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, class-design

I'm studying some source codes and I'm just wondering why a class (or classes) is often implemented this way:

```
class EventHandler
{
...
    EventDispatcher* m_Dispatcher;
    virtual bool ProcEvent( EventHandler* Sender, int Task, int Event, void* Param );
...
};

class ClassA: public EventHandler
{
...
    ClassA* m_Impl;
    ClassA* m_Iface;
...
public:
    // virtual functions
    virtual bool ProcEvent( EventHandler* Sender, int Task, int Event, void* Param );
    virtual void OnDataWritten(const PIOResult&) {;}
    ...

    // sample functions
    void SetImplement( ClassA* aImpl );
    void SetInterface( ClassA* aIface );
    ClassA* GetImplement() { return m_Impl; }
    ClassA* GetInterface() { return m_Iface; }
    bool GetData( list& aList );
};

// Implementation of some sample functions; Most of its function contain more
// or less the same format as below, with the return m_Impl->XXX having the same
// name as the function being defined (e.g. A::XXX)
bool ClassA::GetData( list< Data >& aList )
{
    if( m_Impl )
        return m_Impl->GetData( aList );
    else
        return false;
}

class ClassAFactory: public EventHandler
{
private:
    ClassAFactory* m_Impl;
    ClassAFactory* m_Iface;

protected:
    virtual ClassA* MakeTransport();

    virtual bool ProcEvent( EventHandler* Sender, int Task, int Event, void* Param );
    virtual ClassA* CreateClassA() { return 0; }

...
};

// In some member function of ClassB (ClassB inherits ClassA)

switch( status )
{
    case 1:
        GetInterface()->OnDataWritten();
    case 2:
        // ...
};
```

I believe it's for some design pattern but I'm not familiar with it. It could help me understand if I know what it is. Can anyone help me point out which it could be or what is the use of these classes such that it is implemented this way?

I think it's for some event handling and used together with some factory but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you give a bigger hint about how this is used? If I didn't know any better, I would say it's written by someone who has a basic misunderstanding of object-oriented programming. Otherwise, they are unwisely overloading the meanings of some heavily used words.

Comment: This reminds me of OO hacks done in straight C where you use a pointer to different versions of the same sturct to mirror some OO features.

Comment: I've added some more, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid the names used do not have the `usual` meaning, so without examples of what is put in or how they are used, it's going to be difficult to guess.

There are 2 design patterns that you should check, that make heavy use of this kind of `self-recursion` (at class level*):

- [The Decorator Pattern](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/decorator.html)
- [The Composite Pattern](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/composite.html)

And I am afraid that you are looking at something that fails to emulate either of those.

In the `Decorator`, the point is to add functionality. To this end you have an `Interface` of which derives a `Concrete` class and a `Wrapper` interface. Then various wrappers will derive of `Wrapper` and you can chain them:

```
Interface* interface = new Wrapper2( new Wrapper1 ( new Concrete() ) );
```

Each wrapper add some functionality, whereas here we only have perfect forwarding... so it's not a `Decorator`.

The `Composite` pattern is different. Its goal is to hide whether you treat with a collection of elements or a single element. The usual example is a tree: you can apply operations either to an entire subtree or just a leaf node if it's implemented with a `Composite` Pattern.

Once more, there is not such thing here.

So my best guess is that you have either a wild design (perhaps a misguided attempt to emulate a well-known pattern) or you haven't given enough information (source code) for us to figure out the role. It seems strange anyway.

*Note: by `self-recursion` at class level I mean that an object of class `A` points to another object of class `A`, but this does not mean (certainly) that it points to the same instance... otherwise we would have a Stack Overflow (pun intended). This *not the same instance* bit is certainly worth checking during the `SetImplementation` call: note that any cyclic reference would cause death by recursion.

Comment: I agree with "And I am afraid that you are looking at something that fails to emulate either of those."

Comment: @Matthieu: Any idea about the relationship between the ClassA and the ClassAFactory? Is this another design pattern?

Comment: @jasonline: the name suggest a `Factory` or perhaps an `AbstractFactory`, once again the term is heavily used without always strictly adhering to the pattern described by the Gang of Four. Without implementation it's difficult to say, and those `m_Impl` and `m_Interface` don't make more sense than for `ClassA`...

Answer (score 2):

I wild guess, but could it be the "pimpl idiom" you are looking for? http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1794.asp

***EDIT***
The expanded code sample with the implementation of GetData is definitely an example of the pimpl idiom. However that does not explain the `m_Iface` member. Can you provide an example of where that is used too?

***EDIT2***
With the added example of how m_Iface is shown it is clear i was wrong regarding the pimpl. It is a kind of decorator. The m_Impl points to the underlying object, while the m_Iface points to the outermost layer, so that an underlying object can make a call which goes through the entire chain of decorators. This example is a bit complicated as ClassA both is the interface class and the default implementation. If you would like to create a decorator to the class you will have to inherit ClassA.

Comment: I don't think it's a pimpl idiom. If it is, the implementation pointer should be pointing to another class right. But in my code above, it is pointing to the class itself.

Comment: Hmm.. you're right... then it more looks like a "decorator" pattern implementation, but still that does not explain the m_Iface member.

Comment: I've added some info on how the m_Iface is called. Meanwhile, I'll check the decorator pattern.

Comment: Any idea how the factory and the normal class should be related? Is it another design pattern perhaps?

Comment: The factory looks like flawed implementation of the "Abstract Factory" pattern. I think it is flawed because CreateClassA is implemented as a stub doing nothing instead of a pure virtual method. As Matthieu points out below, I think that the one writing the code had an ambition to implement several patterns, but didn't completely succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks much more C than C++. In any object-oriented language, you would use inheritance and virtual functions to get this behaviour.

Using an internal pointer to an implementation class is perfectly fine (the pimpl idiom), but this pointer would not normally be accessible to callers. And I don't get the interface pointer at all.

Comment: @Gorpik, I've added more classes. I think it's for some event handling and used together with some factory. Yes, I don't get the use of the interface pointer. I couldn't find yet where it is used.

Comment: @Gorpik: I've added sample function where the interface is used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a classic example of the `pimpl` idiom, but if so, the point is to separate the interface (which should be stable) from the implementation details (which you should be relatively free to change).